# Disjoint Union in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, disjoint-union

I have two sets (ILists) where I need all the items from the 1st list, where the item is not in the second list.

Can anyone point me to the best way of achieving this with a LINQ statement?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

How about the [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) method:

```
var firstMinusSecond = first.Except(second);
```