# How to get elements from collection A that not in collection B? i.e. A-B

Tags: c#, linq, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disjoint Union in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801757/disjoint-union-in-linq)

**DUPE**: [Disjoint Union in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801757/disjoint-union-in-linq)

I know this is a simple collection operation,My code is:

```
var gone = from a in A
     where B.Contains(a) == false
     select a;
```

but it not work.

Comment: *nods to Marc for swinging that Mod Hammer ;)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var gone = A.Except(B);
```